# google sheets submit button to a new sheet

Tags: javascript

I am working on an inventory sheet that will allow me to input data into one sheet, hit a button and this button will clear data and then append it to the next sheet in a specified column. I have to keep inventory of 10 items so there will be 10 columns that I would like this data continuously added to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e){
// Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B7'){
var input = e.range.getValue();
e.range.clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var inputSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("input")
var masterSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("master inventory");

var currentRow = inputSheet.getRange("C7").getValue(); 

masterSheet.getRange("A3:A1000").getCell(currentRow, 1).setValue(input);
inputSheet.getRange("C7").setValue(currentRow + 1);
}
}
```